# oracle ordim add watermark to image

Tags: java, oracle, image-processing, watermark, multimedia

Oracle ordim is library that is bundled with oracle 11g database its purpose is to manage multimedia content in the database. How to add watermark using it? This is the function that is built in ".applyWatermark" but it just doesn't work with me. I have oracle 11g database installed so i use its ordim library. here is demo code.

```
imgProxy.applyWatermark(imgProxy, imgProxy, strings);
```

first attribute is source image, second is destination image and string should be the text of the watermark, note source and destination images are same in my case. How can i add simple TEXT or image watermark to it. Can anyone post a working example. I have searching for online documentation but official oracle documentation is not enought for me to get it to work. Please help guys

Edit:

This is the code that "compiles" without errors but i don't have any output at the end. What am i doing wrong here?

```
String []strings = new String[3];
strings[0]="test1";
strings[1]="test2";
strings[2]="test3";
imgProxy.applyWatermark(imgProxy, imgProxy, strings);
imgProxy.getDataInFile("C://Documents and Settings//Administrator//Desktop//slika.jpg");
```

Note when i compile it only with this line

`imgProxy.getDataInFile("C://Documents and Settings//Administrator//Desktop//slika.jpg");`

it will generate me image on desktop but without watermark. So problem is only in that watermark method.

Answer (score 1):

The function is listed in [Multimedia Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10776/ch_imgref.htm#CHDCHIBH), but not the [Multimedia DICOM Java API Reference (Javadoc)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10781/oracle/ord/dicom/OrdDicom.html).  The Multimedia Reference has an example of applying a watermark, although it's in PL/SQL.  It also includes this note:

> You cannot specify the same ORDImage as both the source and
>   destination.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice, i will try to use different source and destination, and it would greater help to me if that example is made in java then in PLSQL but i guess sometimes in life you have to do things hard way. I will try today to figure what is the problem.